# как в класс регистрации добавить отправку мыла

Tags: php, sendmail

В общем у меня есть класс register, и я не могу добавить к нему PhpMailer, хотя если я делаю тестовую страницу для отправки сообщения(без регистрации) то все гуд 
вот код register.php :

```
 include('connection.php');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    /**
    User Registeration
    */
    class Register
    {
    private $db;
    private $connection;
    function __construct()
    {
    //constructor call
    $this->db = new Connection();
    $this->connection=$this->db->get_connection();
    }
     public function does_user_exist($username, 
    $time_od,$name,$pass_md5,$status,$rank,$time_left,$password,$company,$mor_id)
    {
      // does user already exist or not
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
      $result=mysqli_query($this->connection,$query);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
      $json['status']=400;
      $json['message']=' Sorry '.$username.' is already exist.';
      echo json_encode($json);
      mysqli_close($this->connection);
     }else {
     $status = "user";
     $query="INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,status,ima,id_time, 
     Rank,mor_id,left_time,pass_text,company) VALUES 
     ('$username','$pass_md5','$status','$name', 
     '$time_od','$rank','$mor_id','$time_left','$password','$company')";
      $is_inserted=mysqli_query($this->connection,$query);
      if($is_inserted == 1){



      $json['status']=200;
      $json['message']='Account created, Welcome '.$name;





      }else {
      $json['status']=401;
      $json['message']='Something wrong';
      }
       echo json_encode($json);
       mysqli_close($this->connection);
      }
      }  

 }


 if($_GET['api_key']=="w5vt2bjzf8ryp63t"){
 $register=new Register();
 if(isset($_GET['username'],$_GET['name'],$_GET['password'],$_GET['company'],$_GET['rank']))
 {
   $rank = $_GET['rank'];
   $name= addslashes(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['name'])));
   $new_name = str_replace("%2520", " ", $name);
   $username=$_GET['username'];
   $company=$_GET['company'];
   $pass=$_GET['password'];
   $time_od = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $time_left = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("$time_od+14 day"));
   $mor_id = $_GET['mor_id'];
 if (!empty($name) && !empty($pass) && !empty($company) && !empty($username) && !empty($rank) && !empty($mor_id)) {
     $encrypted_password=md5($pass);
     $register-> does_user_exist($username,$time_od,$new_name,$encrypted_password,$status,$rank,$time_left,$pass,$company,$mor_id);
     //$register->sendMail($username,$pass,$new_name);



   }else {
$json['status']=100;
     $json['message']='You must fill all the fields';
     echo json_encode($json);
   }
 }
 }else{
     $json['status']=401;
     $json['message']='You dont permission';
     echo json_encode($json);

 }
```

как мне в этот код нормально сделать после регистрации сразу отправку письма а то оно мне пишет 500 Internal Server Error
сам код отправки у меня вот такой:

```
     require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $filename = " BOOKS MANUAL.pdf"; //Имя файла для прикрепления
                 $to = "$username"; //Кому
                 $to_name = "$new_name";
                 $from = "from@exmpl.com"; //От кого

                 $subject = "Registered on  Books  Service"; //Тема
                 $message = "<br>Dear Sir</br>,
                 <br> You are registered on  Books  Service.</br>
                   <br>Your login: <b>$username</b></br>
                   <br>Your password:<b> $pass</b></br>
                   <br>This service will give you opportunity to get familiar with your employer ISM manuals and other necessary information for your successful onboard performance. </br>
                   <br> In attachments you will find detailed instruction how to use  Books Service and login procedure.</br>  
                   <br> Questions for familiarization you will receive separately on you e-mail.</br> 
                   <br>Kindly yours,  Crewing.</br>";
                 $withouthtml = "Dear Sir,
                   You are registered on  Books  Service.
                   Your login: $username
                   Your password:$pass
                   This service will give you opportunity to get familiar with your employer ISM manuals and other necessary information for your successful onboard performance.
                    In attachments you will find detailed instruction how to use  Books Service and login procedure. 
                    Questions for familiarization you will receive separately on you e-mail. 
                   Kindly yours,  Crewing.";
                 $host = "mail.examp.com";///smtp.gmail.com smtp.mailtrap.io
                 $port = 587;//25
                 $user = "user@exam.com";///74b72b4009b837
                 $passwordhost = "***********";///6236d8a642837e
                 $path = ' BOOKS MANUAL.pdf';


                $mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

                 $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                 $mail->Host = $host;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                 $mail->Username = $user;                 // SMTP username
                 $mail->Password = $passwordhost;                           // SMTP password
                 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                 $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                 $mail->setFrom($from, 'Y.Kuchmij');
                 $mail->addAddress($to, $to_name);     // Add a recipient



                 $mail->addAttachment(' BOOKS MANUAL.pdf');    // Optional name
                 if($company =="HELICON")
                 {
                    $mail->addAttachment( "docs/doc.docx")
                 }
                 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

                 $mail->Subject = $subject;
                 $mail->Body    = $message;
                 $mail->AltBody = $withouthtml;

                 if(!$mail->send()){

                    echo 'Error send msg'.  $mail->ErrorInfo;
                 }
```

Comment: Ошибка 500 говорит об ошибке в коде. Ее можно найти в логах. Приложите ее

Comment: @AlexBrin сожалению у меня нет ничего такого в логах

Comment: Добавьте в начало исполняемого скрипта (с которого отправляется запрос) error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Всем спасибо, особенно за вывод ошибок, в общем проблема была в том что   мне нужно было приатачивать либо один файл либо 2,  вот из-за этого и были ошибки, тему можно закрыть